# What is a unit of PrintOptions.PageContentHeight in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

What is a unit of [PrintOptions.PageContentHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms225982%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? I thought that it is hundredths of an inch but it seems that it is not.

Following figure shows my page setup:
[image]

But following code return different result:

```
ReportDocument rp = new ReportDocument();
rp.Load(path_to_my_report_file);
Console.WriteLine(rp.PrintOptions.PageContentHeight);
Console.WriteLine(rp.PrintOptions.PageContentWidth);
```

Output:

```
8392
5670
```

where `ReportDocument` is from `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` namespace.

What is a unit of `PrintOptions.PageContentHeight`  and why it differs from Crustal Designer PageSetup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units are in [twips](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3380601).

`1440 twips = 1 inch`